# Problem with downloading Scene Builder via Maven

Tags: maven, javafx, scenebuilder, builder, scene

I wanted to start writing my JavaFX project with Maven (it's my first time using this tool), but I have problems with downloading Scene Builder package via dependencies. I'm using code [provided on this site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq.scenebuilder/scenebuilder/8.5.0) in my `pom.xml` file, but Maven downloads weird files instead of `.jar` files and documentation:
here's the image of these files.

[image]

Every of these files has similar text:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Tue Oct 23 13:41:13 CEST 2018
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1540294873693
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get "lastUpdated" files, it means something went wrong during the download and Maven won't try to download them again before a given time. Just delete those files in your local repository and retry.

Comment: I did it a few times but nothing happened, I still get those files.

Comment: Here's what I got: https://pastebin.com/LbUb99U8
It probably means I can't download it via Maven, so are there any options to add Scene Builder to my project? This is a group project so I prefer to have all packages in one place and easy to download.
I also found the files on the author's page: http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/scenebuilder/8.5.0/
Is it possible to copy the files from this link in Maven to my project?

Comment: You sure could add it manually in your local repository. Download the jar and then enter `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<PATH>/scenebuilder-8.5.0-all.jar -DgroupId=com.gluonhq.scenebuilder 
-DartifactId=scenebuilder -Dversion=8.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar`. But I don't get why Maven is not downloading it from the repo...